# How to Approach Database Testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I am currently working on building a URL shortener using Flask. I feel fairly comfortable writing the code for the application, however, I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how to write the tests.

The MVP for the application does 2 functions:

(1) Given a long url in a post, returns a short url

(2) Given a short url in a get, redirects to the destination

My general code structure is as follows

```
url_shortener
    url_shortener
       controller.py
       setup.sh # sets up virtual env, installs requirements, creates database if it doesn't exist, spins up application
       lib/ # contains functionality to shorten urls
       tests/ # Unit, integration, etc tests
```

From what I've read, I believe I would want to set up a fresh instance of a database for each unit test I have. For example, say I wanted to test that the first long url -> short url conversion yielded http://myendpointurl/0. This wouldn't work if I used the application's "real" database if there was anything already in it. Conceptually, I understand what I need to do, however, I am getting confused as to how to put it into code.

I've tried looking around for a few examples but am having trouble finding ones that don't have a lot of new and unfamiliar technologies (example: https://github.com/cgil/shortener - I haven't worked with fab files, alembic, nose for testing (I use py.test), etc) or ones with tests (ex: https://github.com/richyvk/flask-url-shortener).

- Does anyone know if there is existing documentation that walks you through this at a somewhat beginner level? I'm pretty good with most non-web application Python, have built 1 flask endpoint before, and generally use py.test.
- If not, if someone could help elaborate on how to approach this, that would be wonderful.

Comment: You should look into in-memory databases; these are often used for testing as they're faster and can easily be torn down and re-built, and actual persistence isn't a big deal for tests.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at URL shorteners is probably the wrong place. Instead, look into the general techniques for setting up test databases, and mocking database operations. For example, [this blog post about integration testing databases in Python](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2014/db-integration-testing-strategies-python) and the Python [unitest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.mock.html) library.